# Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingField.TrackingFieldDetailsPage throws exception

Tags: xdb, paas

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 in PAAS and in specific environment we are getting error on OOB tracking field on all the pages

We don't have Sitecore XDb in scope and XDb is not enabled.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingField.TrackingFieldDetailsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +595
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +153
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +250
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4081

Any idea how do we fix this error

Comment: We are currently trying to upgrade to sitecore 9 and we're getting the same issue with our implementation

Comment: Did you solve the issue, I am having the same one on my sitecore 10 implementation